# WindowsError: [Error 126] when loading a DLL with ctypes

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

This works fine on Windows 7 with Python 2.7:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('prov_means')
provmeans = lib.provmeans
```

The library prov_means.DLL is in my working directory. It exports a simple, stand-alone C function provmeans() with no dependencies.

When I try the same thing on Windows XP and Python 2.7 I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Auxil\src\auxil.py", line 130, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('prov_means')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have tried copying the DLL to Windows\System32 and also entering the full path name

```
"d:\\python\\auxil\\src\\prov_means"
```

with and without the ".DLL" extension. Nothing works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Error 126 is what you get when a dependent DLL can not be found. There are two obvious causes for this:

1. Your DLL is not being located.
2. Your DLL depends on other DLLs that cannot be found.

I doubt that option 1 is the problem but in any case I think I would probably be using a full path to that DLL to be sure.

So that leaves option 2 and the most common cause for that is that your target machine does not have the C++ runtime installed. Either install the C++ runtime on your target machine, or use static linking, [`/MT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx), when building your DLL so that you do not need to redistribute the runtime.

Probably, on the machine that you developed the DLL, you have installed a C++ compiler and that installed the runtime for you. On your target machine, where the code fails, you have not installed the compiler and so the runtime is not present.

Comment: Thanks David. That sounded very plausible as I compiled on the Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2010 Express, which is not on the target machine. I installed the C++ runtime on the target machine as suggested and restarted. Same error unfortunately.

Comment: You could use Dependency Walker in profile mode to check this. But I'd consider rebuilding the DLL with `/MT` just to double check that it is not that dependency that is causing the problem.

Comment: Right, just rebuilt with /MT and it now runs on the target. Many thanks!

Comment: I think that means that you could solve the problem by installing the re-dist, but for a simple DLL then `/MT` is the easiest option. It lets your DLL stand alone.

Comment: Using /MT just blows it up from 28kB to 132kB so no problem and stand alone is really what I prefer for later distribution. Super!

Comment: This has been really helpful to me. Just googling it brought me to this post and am glad I found the solution so quickly with your help.

Comment: I am trying to load `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/libgeos_c-1.dll`. Everything is fine when I inspect the DLL with DependencyWalker (dependencies are met). I installed `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679` and rebooted by I still get the 126 error. The problem is, I didn't build the DLL myself, it came from PostgreSQL binary install. I'm stuck now...

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpfull to me. It only works on the machine whre it is built.

Comment: How did you do /MT?

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler did you use to build the library? Maybe some required libraries are missing? You can check what dependencies the library has with Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)?