# Python Error "WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm running a python script importing dataextract (from tableau api) csv,os, and datetime
when I run it I'm getting this error and I don't know where to start looking.The only line of code I am running is

```
import dataextract as tde
```

And I installed this library following tableau's tutorial
http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/extract-api-introduction?signin=f850b055b106d24b93b365faad64838f

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Ofri Harlev/Documents/Python/TableauFlatScript.py", line 1, in <module>
import dataextract as tde
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dataextract\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from Base import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dataextract\Base.py", line 17, in <module>
from . import StringUtils
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dataextract\StringUtils.py", line 17, in <module>
tablib = libs.load_lib
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dataextract\Libs.py", line 35, in load_lib
self.lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(self.lib_path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411709/windowserror-error-126-when-loading-a-dll-with-ctypes)?

Comment: I'm running on windows 7 and the library shouldn't be dependent on anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying everything I found that the Tableau Extract Library only works on computers were Tableau is installed

Comment: Well, dataextract module works just fine in my computer, and I only have Tableau Reader installed in my machine.

Comment: I didn't have Tableau Reader installed either

Comment: Does it work when you install just Tableau Reader? This is something important to know

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem while working with Python 2.7 and this is what I found:

-- Problem was coming because I have **installed multiple versions of python** (Python3.2, Python3.5 etc).

-- Because of multiple versions, at runtime **there was multiple DLLs with same name** (in all python versions library). So it was **unable to figure out which one to load**.

**Solution**:
I have **uninstalled all python versions except one I needed (Python2.7)** at time. Then run the program and now everything was working fine for me.