# Rebuilding DLL with static linking

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes, static-linking

I am trying to run a Python script that uses the mido module for MIDI processing.  The script works great in Linux but I'm getting an error in Windows, even after installing all the same modules.  The end of the Traceback ends with:

```
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mido\backends\portmidi_init.py", line 20, in <module>
   lib = CDLL(dll_name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__ 
   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411709/windowserror-error-126-when-loading-a-dll-with-ctypes) which seems like an identical problem.

That solution recommends 1) Installing the C++ runtime (which I have done - same error) or 2) rebuilding the DLL with static linking.

My issue is that I'm a relatively amateur programmer and I don't know what is meant by "rebuilding a DLL with static linking".  Unfortunately the Microsoft [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) referenced in the above solution is a bit over my head.  I should also mention that I don't know which DLL is being referenced in this code, so I'm not even sure which DLL to rebuild.

Can anyone provide new insight into this error or give me a simple explanation of how to rebuild a DLL with static linking?  I am happy to post the full Traceback if its useful but it seemed like an inefficient use of space.

EDIT:

I have not figured out how to properly build portmidi on Windows, but I ended up using the Pygame backend for Mido and it worked fine.

Comment: If you can try to figure out what the value of `self._name` is in the failing call to _dlopen you're halfway. I don't know enough about Python myself, but imagine it cannot be that hard, it's interpreted so I'd guess there is a way to make it trace each call while printing variables or so. Anyway, once you find that, find the dll and load it into Dependency Walker to see which dependencies it misses and add this info to the question. Or, if te dll is nowhere to be found at all, also add it here.

Comment: The tool I reach for to figure out what could not be found is [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Use the filter tool to watch `CreateFile` operations and the `python.exe` process name.  Cause the error and read the log for files that are never found.

Comment: Thank you for the Procmon recommendation.  It appears that I'm missing a dll for portmidi which is the MIDI backend that the mido module uses by default.  I am having difficulty installing portmidi correctly so I'm exploring some alternatives at this point.