# Error when loading DLL: "The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, ctypes

Full disclosure: I've never used DLLs before and I'm an inexperienced programmer so please ask for clarification if this doesn't make sense.  I'm trying to use a specific API but keep getting an error when loading the DLL.  The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LabUser\Documents\CANbus\content\code\ecomcat_api\apply_brakes.py.py", line 4, in <module>
    mydll = CDLL('Debug\\ecomcat_api')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

As other answers have suggested, I have tried modifying the string path to the DLL as well as updating the registry subkey, neither of which worked.  Any ideas on why I am getting this [Error 126]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 126\] when loading a DLL with ctypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411709/windowserror-error-126-when-loading-a-dll-with-ctypes)

Comment: Check that you aren't missing dependent DLLs. You could test that by copying that DLL and any DLLs in the same folder or in downstream folders into the path of your script and see if that helps.